# how to print 2D array in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, 2d

I have a 2D array nxn, and I would like to print the content of it on the screen.

```
board = { (i,j):"-" for i in range(n) for j in range(n) }
#print(board)

def display_board():
   for row in board:
      for column in board[row]:
         print(board[row,column])
```

The output will look like this:

```
----
----
----
----
```

for 4x4 for example.

My code above gives me error. I am new to python, and need quick help please.

Thanks!

Comment: Why you are storing indices and value as key-value pair?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
n =4
arr = [['_' for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
for row in arr:
    print(*row)
```

**Output:**

```
_ _ _ _
_ _ _ _
_ _ _ _
_ _ _ _
```